# variable not taking in ansible jinja template

Tags: ansible-template

I have created jinja2 template to generate my json file with below code.
my variables are below:

```
network_profile:
- Internal
- Custom
```

if I used above 2 variable then I am not getting output as mention below. the v_value of second loop become custom. I want it as Internal

Instead of if I used 3 variable then it work fine and getting below output as per my requirement. any idea where i missing

```
{
    "p_data": [
        {
            "u_label": "Internal",
            "u_catalog_item": "abc",
            "u_value": "Internal"
        },
        {
            "u_label": "Custom",
            "u_catalog_item": "abc",
            "u_value": "Internal"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
{
    "p_data": [
        {% for network in network_profile %}
            {% if loop.index == loop.length %}
            {
              "u_label": "{{ network }}",
              "u_catalog_item": "{{ catalog_item }}",
              "u_value": "{{ network }}"
            }

          {% else %}
            {
              "u_label": "{{ network }}",
              "u_catalog_item": "{{ catalog_item }}",
              "u_value": "Internal"

            },
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what i am looking for is that, dynamic variable in network_profile, If i add new variable then my data should be look below.

```
{
    "p_data": [
        {
            "u_label": "Internal",
            "u_catalog_item": "abc",
            "u_value": "Internal"
        },
        {
            "u_label": "Custom",
            "u_catalog_item": "abc",
            "u_value": "Internal"
        },
        {
            "u_label": "Test",
            "u_catalog_item": "abc",
            "u_value": "Test"
        }
    ]
}
```

only I have condition only "Custom" variable. whenever it come the u_value should be "Internal"

```
    "p_data": [
        {% for network in network_profile %}
            {% if loop.index == loop.length %}
            {
              "u_label": "{{ network }}",
              "u_catalog_item": "{{ catalog_item }}",
              {% if network|string() != 'Custom' %}
              "u_value": "{{ network }}"
              {% else %}
              "u_value": "Internal"
              {% endif %}
            }

          {% else %}
            {
              "u_label": "{{ network }}",
              "u_catalog_item": "{{ catalog_item }}",
              "u_value": "{{ network }}"
            },
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
    ]
}
```